# jQuery How to get element id based on what was clicked AND get child element Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a strange set-up I'm trying to figure out how to get the result I have in my head. I feel like I am very close I just don't know 100% how jQuery operates. I have applied everything into this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usL0uybx/)
Basically, I have five or so section elements. Inside of each of those sections is another section.

The outer section is simply given an id of "outerSect" and then the name of that section such as: "outerSectLogo" (and there is a "outerSect" class that defines some css elements but I don't think that would help me here. Or would it?)

The inner section is, you guessed it, "innerSectLogo"

The goal is to have the innerSections hidden until the user clicks on the outer Section. They are basically categories of a sort and information is stored in each category. I don't want a page full of information. I want the user to choose what information they want, click on it, and then that information appears.

Currently I have this code:

```
    $("#outerSectLogo").click(function() {
$("#innerSectLogo").css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'display' : 'inline'});
});
```

which works GREAT! Except that I have like five other ones I have to do. Now I can "hard code" all of these, simply duplicating this code over and over again just replacing the "outerSectLogo: with "outerSectCovers" and so and so forth with whatever unique name I have for that category.

I'm trying to find a way to be cleaner.
Since each section has similar IDs:
outerSectLogo
outerSectCovers
outerSectBook
outerSectAd
and so on.
The inner sections have the same IDs respectively
innerSectLogo
innerSectCovers
and so on.

I am figuring there is a way where the ID can be capture based upon what the user clicks. Something like

```
<section id="outerSectLogo" onClick="revealSection(logo)">
```

where that "logo" in : "revealSection(logo)" refers to the section ID. Then that "logo" can be inserted into the jQuery code in some fashion like

```
$("#outerSect" + 'x').click(function() {
```

where x is what was in the () of the revealSection, in this case "logo"

I know this is confusing. But I feel like I am on to something. I am generally new to jQuery and would appreciate the help.
https://jsfiddle.net/usL0uybx/

Answer (score 1):

The logic is sound, but you're not using the power of jQuery which is causing the duplication. Since they all serve a similar purpose of a header than contains a hidden span, you want to target them all with a common `class` to remove the redundancy which you already have in your code.  This should handle everything.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".workSect").click(function() {
       $(this).find(".innerSect:first").css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'display' : 'inline'});
    });
});
```

It also looks like there was an error in your HTML causing problems.  I fixed it with the correct jQuery here https://jsfiddle.net/xgp0txzz/

Comment: That solved it! I knew that I was close to something. jQuery's abilities and power still dumbfounds me. I have much too learn! Luckily, doing all this by hand is helping a lot.

Now all I need to do is come up with a plan on how to get the information to collapse when clicked on a second time.

Comment: This would probably be a lot of help for you [jQuery tutorial](http://try.jquery.com/) It gives the jQuery basics and goes over the visibility toggle feature you're looking for. It's totally free and worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

So use a class instead of ids and use find to get the child element that is inside of the one that was clicked.

```
$(".outerSectLogo").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".innerSectLogo").css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'display' : 'inline'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is to assign a common class to all the outer elements like

```
<div id="outerSectLogo" class="innerdisplay <other-classes>"></div>
```

then

```
$('.innerdisplay').click(function(){
    $("#" + this.id.replae('outer', 'inner')).css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'display' : 'inline'});
})
```