# jQuery - on click class - get other classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see my previous question which I've solved with the help of the fine StackOverFlow Community, here: [jQuery How to get element id based on what was clicked AND get child element Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017178/jquery-how-to-get-element-id-based-on-what-was-clicked-and-get-child-element-id/31017376)

which brings me to my current issue involving similar code as the above post.

Currently, I have a set of categories (sections) that when clicked the inner information (inner section) becomes visible. Then, when clicked again, the information is re-hidden.

My question is: since I have 5 or more outer sections, how can I have it so when I click on ONE of those sections, it grabs the names of the other sections and closes them? Because as it stands if I have one open and I go to open another both will remain open. If the user opens one I would prefer if the others would close.

Also, the way I have the code now, when one is open it takes two clicks on another section to open it. Please review the JSFiddle.

Please see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5k46e4sr/3/) for a working example if this is confusing.
**but I've come across an issue that is prevelant with both my code and the one provided down below. I only mean to have the sections open and close when the outer section is clicked. But as it stands, the inner section when clicked also closes the section. I don't want that because the inner sections will have some interactive elements**
Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var isClicked = 0;
var whatsClicked;
$(".workSect").click(function() {
    isClicked++;
    whatsClicked = $(this).find(".innerSect")
    //alert(isClicked);
    clickerCheck();
});
function clickerCheck() {
    if(isClicked == 1){
        whatsClicked.first().css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'display' : 'inline'});
        //alert(isClicked);
    }
    else if(isClicked >= 2){
        whatsClicked.first().css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'display' : 'none'});
        isClicked = 0;
    }
    else {
        whatsClicked.first().css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'display' : 'none'});
        isClicked = 0;      
        }
}
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/5k46e4sr/3/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a counter, just check the visibility

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $inners = $('.workSect .innerSect');
  $(".workSect").click(function() {
    var $inner = $(this).find('.innerSect'),
      visible = $inner.is(':visible');
    $inner.css({
      'visibility': visible ? 'hidden' : 'visible',
      'display': visible ? 'none' : 'block'
    });
    $inners.not($inner).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#workPort {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.workSect {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.workSect h2 {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.arrowImg {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.innerSect {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
.innerSectVis {
  visibility: visible;
}
#innerSectLogo {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="workPort">
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectLogo">
    <h2>Logo - Business Card Design</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectLogo">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectCovers">
    <h2>Publication Covers</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectCovers">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectBook">
    <h2>Book Covers</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectBook">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectAd">
    <h2>Advertisements</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectAd">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectBanner">
    <h2>Banner Advertisements</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectBanner">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectMotion">
    <h2>Motion Advertisements</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectLogo">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectOther">
    <h2>Other Designs</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectOther">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</article>
```

---

It can be simplified if you don't want to set visibility rule

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $inners = $('.workSect .innerSect');
  $(".workSect").click(function() {
    var $inner = $(this).find('.innerSect').toggle();
    $inners.not($inner).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#workPort {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.workSect {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.workSect h2 {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.arrowImg {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.innerSect {
  display: none;
}
.innerSectVis {
  visibility: visible;
}
#innerSectLogo {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="workPort">
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectLogo">
    <h2>Logo - Business Card Design</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectLogo">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectCovers">
    <h2>Publication Covers</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectCovers">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectBook">
    <h2>Book Covers</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectBook">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectAd">
    <h2>Advertisements</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectAd">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectBanner">
    <h2>Banner Advertisements</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectBanner">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectMotion">
    <h2>Motion Advertisements</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectLogo">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="fluid workSect" id="outerSectOther">
    <h2>Other Designs</h2>
    <img src="imgs/elements/arrow_right.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="arrowImg" />
    <hr/>
    <section class="fluid innerSect" id="innerSectOther">
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
      <p>Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content. Some content.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: That's extremely helpful. I will have to examine your code throughly to understand how that works. (little new to jQuery)

but I've come across an issue that is prevelant with both my code and the one you provided. I only mean to have the sections open and close when the outer section is clicked. But as it stands, the inner section when clicked also closes the section. I don't want that because the inner sections will have some interactive elements.